# "To hear" meaning

Tags: meaning, grammar

I have a great deal of difficulty understanding the correct meaning of this dialogue from the Pink Panther animated series:
"To hear Harry, you'd think (or you think, I'm not sure) you didn't have a right to protect your own property". 
What does "to hear Harry" means here? Is it some sort of conditional sentence and means something like "if you hear Harry"? My second question is which of the "you'd think" or "you think" should be used in such a sentence? 
Here's the link to that animation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzNMgDtnu4U
The aforementioned dialogue is heard in the minute 3:30 . Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: "If you hear Harry" is close. Replacing "To hear Harry" with "If you listen to Harry" produces a sentence with the same meaning. If you use "you think," it's as though you're actually explaining to someone how to hear Harry, which I doubt is what you want.

Comment: In any case the "didn't" means you have to use "you'd."

Comment: Why does your link take me to a performance by Pink Panzer?

Comment: 'To hear Harry ...' means 'When you take into consideration what Harry has said / is saying  about the subject, ...'.

Comment: "You'd" is a contraction for "you would."